# iPhone: Is it possible to send Push-Notifications from a website?

Tags: iphone, web, push-notification

I'd like to be notified of certain events on my webserver with a push notification from my website to my iPhone. Is this somehow possible, or do I have to install/create a special App for this?

Comment: You'd be better off with a spam filter and flood protection.

Comment: This would be possible too, but sometimes some 'friends' of mine spam with some crapply content about me ^^ they won't get into any spam filter, and I want them to be deleted anyway ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely send notifications triggered from a website: you just have to hook up the backend to do so. See this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154443/push-notification-guide) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use Push Notification it would have to be a native iPhone app on your phone. You might be able to set up some sort of email notification coming from your website and turn on push notifications for your mail client on your iPhone.

In regards to @gnuf's post (Sorry it wouldn't let me comment on your post) Your web server can  act as the Provider of Push Notifications but will still require a native application on the phone to receive the notifications.

Comment: Yeah, this would be nice, but which service does support push? I just know Microsoft Exchange, but I don't have an address on an exchange server. Which services can I use?

Comment: If you have a gmail account. The native google app can receive push notifications when a new message comes in.

Comment: You can set up the default mail app to recieve push notifications from Gmail, you have to set it up as an Exchange account, look it up on Google.